# Docker network change kills connectivity

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker composer file that I run on a Ubuntu server

Sometimes, when I run the command to run it, I suddenly see:

```
Creating network "cms-docker-new_default" with the default driver
```

This hangs and kills my SSH session over VPN.
When this happens the server is no longer accessible to me from the VPN side. I have to login to the local network computer (local to the ubuntu server) in order to have SSH access to the server work again. Note that the docker file never touches port 22 (not used in any app).

Docker is making network changes for some reason and I don't know why.

```
    br-05fb571c05ec: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
            ether 02:42:67:0a:e1:d2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
            inet6 fe80::42:eff:fe6d:d72  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 02:42:0e:6d:0d:72  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 510254  bytes 28973063 (28.9 MB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 851086  bytes 2046796317 (2.0 GB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I either disable the interfaces or run (connected via local network)

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down
```

When this happens, I see

```
Removing network cms-docker-new_default
```

And the network comes back and I can access it over VPN again

Comment: It could be having a conflict in IP ranges with your host machine? What are the settings for your docker compose defined network? If you have the same ip-range or dhcp setings it might try to wrongly route your traffic.

Comment: The VPN IP range is completely different than the one for the LAN in which the machine with docker resides.

This issue happens sometimes. It's very random

Comment: Very hard to say where exactly the problem resides. Especially if it only occurs sometimes. My guess would be with the host OS which could have some cronjob running which flushes network. Have you tried creating a new docker network and giving it some different parameters? Maybe someone else has any more advice.

Comment: @JustLudo - Yes, this seems like a bug in docker, but I don't know where to start to debug it